# Identify first call using already existing static variables?

Tags: c++, gcc, static-variables

Is there a way I can identify if a function is being called the for the first time by identifying the internal (hidden?) variables that GCC uses to facilitate static variables (variables that already exist in my function)?

I hope to get at these variables from the C++ code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GCC uses a hidden flag indicating if a variable has been initialized. There is no way to access this. Even so, these don't actually track the "first time" but rather whether the variable has been initialized. Consider the following:

```
void func()
{
   static T a;
   static T b;
}
```

But the standard would actually allow that these are initialized by different threads. So if that happens which one got their first. Checking the gcc disassembly it does seem each is handled with its own lock, at least in non-optimized mode, the code changes a lot in optimized mode (so even moreso, "first time" is not clearly defined).

Additionally, as Mark points out in his comment, it greatly depends on what type you are using when the initialization is done. Simple types might, not guaranteed, be initialized globally, others will indeed wait until the function is called first.

Why do you need to know first time entry anyway?

Answer (score 5):

There's no way to rely on internals of the compiler, and even if you tried there's no guarantee it wouldn't change with the next version.

Use this common idiom:

```
static bool firsttime = true;
if (firsttime)
{
    firsttime = false;
    // other stuff here
}
```

Comment: It is indeed a good idiom and anybody trying to do anything else is should be sent to the insane asylum. Nevertheless, is it possible to do what I want to do with GCC?

Comment: @Misha, simple POD types will be initialized at compile time and there won't be any run-time support required. Static variables requiring a constructor or initialized with a run-time value will be initialized as the line of code is executed, but I don't know what mechanism gcc uses. As I say in the answer, gcc is free to change the mechanism with every release so it's truly crazy to even try to figure it out.

Comment: In terms of thread-safety this is not a good idiom since multiple calllers can end up in the firsttime block.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y, good point. I don't work much with multiple threads so I don't run into that problem.